# zImage install on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: boot, kernel, operating-systems, android

I have precompiled Android Kernel and modified it. After builduing I got an zImage. The Question is how can I install and boot the zImage on my raspberry pi 2?

I'm using a SD-card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the modifications you've made involve incorporating the tweaks that make the [Raspberry Pi kernel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) what it is (I think this is more than simply "ARMv7"), this is doomed to fail, but it is simple enough to try.

First you need a card set up for the pi, the easiest way would be to just use a Raspbian or some other image, and then you can overwrite the root filesystem in the second partition as you see fit (with Android I guess, but again: this is certainly doomed to fail).  The important part is the small first VFAT partition, which contains the bootloader code, etc., and the kernel.  There will be a text file in there, `config.txt`.  Copy your kernel onto this partition, and add a line at the top of the `config.txt` file:

```
kernel=mykernel.img
```

Here `mykernel.img` should be whatever you've named the kernel binary.  You may also want to look at `cmdline.txt`, which contains parameters passed to the kernel by the bootloader.

Lots of documentation, etc., on [the official github page](https://github.com/raspberrypi).  Beware that people have already made various efforts to port Android to the pi and as far as I am aware none of them have been very successful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You wrote that it would fail because of the proccesor arch. As I understand the Pi us also using arm? is it a different version on the Pi and and the Android Kernel?

Comment: ARM is not one single architecture.   I have not done what you want to do or looked closely into it, but as I say it is easy enough to try -- so you might as well.  However, if you are confused or uncertain at this point and it does not work, do not be surprised.